# How can I get the execution time of an SQL query using MySQL Connector in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am working with a Python script using the MySQL connector and I need to analyze the execution time of some queries, I would like to know if there is a command for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just calculate the time it takes to complete the query.

```
from time import time

# your code here

tic = time()
cursor.execute("select * from db.clients")
toc = time()
print toc - tic
```